# Is it possible to send custom animation as a video stream in flash?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, webcam, netstream

I'm using NetStream class to create p2p video conferension. Is it possible to add overlay pictures or animation into video captured from webcam and send reencoded stream to other user?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it isn't. you could however [send](https://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetStream.html#send%28%29) the data along parallely and compose it on the other end. don't know how well synched this will turn out to be in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the HTML AD Plugin

UPDATE The site wouldn't let me add the link to the plugin.  Google **HTML Ad Plugin** and it comes up at playerDIY.